# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use')

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am getting an error (**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use')**) when I try to run the 'node server.js' cmd from the Terminal. It shows an error in my auth.routes.js file.

[image: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use')]

Here is the content of my 'auth.routes.js' file:

```js
import verifySignUp from "../middleware/index.js";
import controller from "../controllers/auth.controller.js";

export default function(app) {
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "x-access-token, Origin, Content-Type, Accept"
    );
    next();
  });

  app.post(
    "/api/auth/signup",
    [
      verifySignUp.checkDuplicateUsernameOrEmail,
      verifySignUp.checkRolesExisted
    ],
    controller.signup
  );

  app.post("/api/auth/signin", controller.signin);
};
```

I refer to it in the 'server.js' file. See below:

```js
// routes
import authRoute from './app/routes/auth.routes.js';
import userRoute from './app/routes/user.routes.js';
app.route = authRoute();
app.route = userRoute();
```

Comment: You aren't passing your app object to the function.

Comment: `function(app)` expects you to pass `app`, otherwise it'll be undefined. `app.route = authRoute(app);`

Comment: When I add this ... import authRoute from './app/routes/auth.routes.js';
import userRoute from './app/routes/user.routes.js';
app.route = authRoute(app);
app.route = userRoute(app); .... I get this error: Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]. It refers to this file: \node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:202

Comment: Thanks to you all for your input! I was trying to follow a training course on PluralSight. I am not very familiar with JS and somehow I got lost. I was not able to get this test environment to work but I might retake the training course again later. The thing I least appreciated here was that someone down-voted my initial issue. I did try to research things before I posted my question. JS is just so new to me. Sorry for not understanding it better. I come from the VB.NET and MS VBA coding world.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating "route" property on "app" object? You don't have to set properties to express's "app" object. What treats to your error - you need to organize your code in this way:

```
// auth.routes.js

import verifySignUp from "../middleware/index.js";
import controller from "../controllers/auth.controller.js";

export default function(app) {
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "x-access-token, Origin, Content-Type, Accept"
    );
    next();
  });

  app.post(
    "/api/auth/signup",
    [
      verifySignUp.checkDuplicateUsernameOrEmail,
      verifySignUp.checkRolesExisted
    ],
    controller.signup
  );

  app.post("/api/auth/signin", controller.signin);
};

// server.js

import initializeAuthRoute from './app/routes/auth.routes.js';
import initializeUserRoute from './app/routes/user.routes.js';
initializeAuthRoute(app);
initializeUserRoute(app);
```